# Set DropDownList selected value in aspx page within a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to set the selected value of a `DropDownList` in an aspx page within a foreach loop. I want the selected value to be set based on a property from the current object within the foreach.

The code is as below.

```
<% foreach (ColorScheme AColorScheme in ColourSchemeList)
       { %>
    <div class="form-horizontal content-row" id="colorSchemeForm" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="alert-info col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1">
                Terminal:&nbsp;
            <%: AColorScheme.TerminalName %>
            </label>&nbsp;
            <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="Colors" ContextTypeName="ColorSchemeParts.ColorSchemeHolder" TableName="AvailableColorSchemes"></asp:LinqDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" SelectedValue="'<%: AColorScheme.ThemeName; %>'" ID="tbTerminalColorScheme" DataSourceID="Colors"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

I am so far unable to access the property `AColorScheme.ThemeName` (I have tried different inline expression tags but so far without any luck) and I am now wondering if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

instead of <%: AColorScheme.ThemeName; %>
use

```
<%# AColorScheme.ThemeName %>
```

or

```
<%= AColorScheme.ThemeName %>
```